# Can I prevent my custom class from being sympified?

Tags: python, sympy

I am building my custom class, which is a subclass of `object`. (No other superclass is in option because of `__r(operator)__` priority.)

Since this class is not `sympy` class, it is sympified whenever I try to apply it to sympy functions, and this is causing troubles.

Is there any way to make it return itself when it is sympified? For example, just like `sympify(sin(x))` returns `sin(x)`, I want the instance of my class to behave in such way: `sympify(instance)` to return `instance`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a def for `_sympy_` in your class: `def _sympy_(self): return self` or maybe `Basic(self)`...but then SymPy won't be able to work with such expressions. Can you give an example of what you are trying to do? There is the CantSympify mixin available, too, but that will prevent the object from being sympified at all.

Comment: You're right... circumventing sympify is causing other problems.

Comment: I am trying to make my object be 'printed' in Array. I added both `_repr_` and `_repr_latex_` methods to my class.
With `display(instance)`, the result of `_repr_latex_` is shown and I'm happy with it. However, when I display `Array([instance, instance])` it shows `[__repr__, __repr__]` instead of two `_repr_latex_`s.

Comment: I found that this is because the element of array is sympified then printed, and sympifying unknown class results its `__repr__` interpreted. Might there be any way to handle this?